# Vertical cracks on newly poured foundation

Tags: foundation

The builder just poured concrete for the foundation of my house. One week later I saw a vertical crack on the back side of the slab. The crack is thin but it goes vertical and also horizontal. It is about 2 feet long. I am so worry that the crack will get bigger later on. Please see attached pictures and give advises.

Comment: If you upload the pictures to imgur.com and include the link in pour posting then someone can inline your pictures for you.

Comment: Why don't you vote up his question so he can load them?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like he back filled the wall too soon, it will crack every time.  And leak.